# How do I get multi dimensional array as result in PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Im trying to get multi dimensional arrays as resulting in my sql query. Its kinda hard to explain so please take a look at my example below.

Here is my SQL code for getting results

```
SELECT
 CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) AS full_name,
 role,
 keyword,
 department
FROM users
JOIN 
 role_module ON role_module.role_uuid = users.role_uuid
JOIN 
 modules ON modules.uuid = role_module.module_uuid
JOIN 
 roles ON roles.uuid = users.role_uuid
JOIN 
 departments ON departments.uuid = users.department_uuid
WHERE 
 users.uuid = :uuid
ORDER BY 
 modules.keyword ASC
```

And here is the result Im getting.

[image]

is it possible to get result like

```
data: Array(1)
 department: "Information Technology"
 full_name: "sonson ixon"
 role: "Super Admin"
 keyword: Array(2)
   [0]: "admin"
   [1]: "employee"
```

Thats the result im trying to get. Since the keyword is the only different result, im trying to insert the values in an array.

Comment: Sounds like you want an ORM which handles these sorts of entity relationships. The way they solve it is to either perform multiple queries (for each relationship) or transform the result to create the nested structure you're after.

Comment: See https://www.slant.co/topics/5639/~php-orms for some suggestions

Comment: I have heard about eloquent. But im not using it as of the moment.

Comment: SQL does not work that way.  Re-think your requirement.

Comment: Yeah. I pretty realize that. I now use GROUP_CONCAT and get result like `value1,value2,etc` seperated by commas then explode the values on my js script to create the array I want. Thanks by the way. :)